# Manipulate the DOM of an external website in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am very new to electron. I would like to load a URL and then run some Javascript which will manipulate the DOM.

I am currently very simply creating a BrowserWindow which loads a URL, and know that I can use webContents.executeJavascript() to pass in a string of Javascript that will be run.

However, I am looking to run setInterval(), and pass in a function which will inspect and potentially manipulate the DOM every x seconds. All of the code to do this is currently in a separate file.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add JavaScript files to your HTML via the [script tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp), as with any HTML site: `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`.

If you want to send an event from the main process as a trigger, use the [webContents of the window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args). This will send an event to the [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) of that window:

```
let mainWindow

const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

data = true // set any data you need for the trigger

mainWindow.webContents.send('trigger', data)
```

Then process the event in the script you added to the HTML file:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

ipcRenderer.on('trigger', (event, data) => {
  yourFunction(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preload in webPreferences. For example:
Load google.com
in main.js

```
let googleWindow;

// handle create googleWindow
function createGoogleWindow(){
    googleWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload:`${__dirname}/scripts/googleWindow.js`
          }});
    //load html into window
    googleWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com/');
    //garbage collection handle
    googleWindow.on('close', function(){
        googleWindow=null;
    });
}
```

Script googleWindow.js referenced above:

```
const electron = require('electron');
function search(){
    const input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
    input.value = "test";
}

setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello");search(); }, 3000);
```

The above script alert "Hello" after 3 seconds, and enter "test" in the search box on google.com.

You can also send an event from the main process as a trigger, use the webContents of the window as pointed out by Melvin Witte.